# Elasticsearch aggregation histogram by date no longer works with script

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

I have an ES query, which returns some 26 results.

The query has aggregation histogram element which looks like this:

```
"aggregations" : {
   "by_date" : {
      "date_histogram" : {
         "field" : "startDate",
         "interval" : "month"
      }
   }
}
```

The aggregation element of search result looks like this:

```
"aggregations": {
   "date_histogram": {
      "buckets":[
        {"key_as_string":"2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "key":1451606400000, "doc_count":18},
        {"key_as_string":"2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z", "key":1454284800000, "doc_count":8}
      ]
   }
}
```

So far so good. But what I want is to do some scripting against search results to remove elements not matching certain criteria. So I added this to the query:

```
"aggregations" : {
   "by_date" : {
      "date_histogram" : {
         "field" : "startDate",
         "interval" : "month",
         "script" : {
            "inline" : "if (condition) {return 1} else {return 0}"
         }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this results a single result bucket and aggregation is lost:

```
"date_histogram": {
   "buckets": [
      {"key_as_string": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "key": 0, "doc_count": 26 }
   ]
}
```

What have I tried:

- reducing the script `inline` element to just `return 1`. This still results broken aggregation
- returning `value` of date field itself. Results `ClassCastException` - the result should be a number
- checking ES config settings. I have enabled everything for `script.engine.groovy.{file|indexed|inline}.{aggs|mapping|search|update|plugin}`, also `script.inline`, `script.indexed` and `script.aggs`.
- Checked the [2.0 breaking aggregation changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_aggregation_changes.html) but none seem to be relevant.

I know I can run separate queries having that filter in query itself (rather than aggregation part) which would let me do aggregation without script. The point is that I have a dozen of different aggregations which take the same set of search results and do different types of filtering (and aggregation). Running the same query multiple times is counter productive and **not acceptable**.

As far as I know, this **used** to work in version 1.4.4 but is no longer working in version 2.2.0.

Is this a bug? Or perhaps the same logic could be reimplemented differently, e.g. via Bucket Script Aggregation, or any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried with the new aggregation framework, and inline ternaries in a groovy style script ?

I previously ran into the same kind of issue, and that's how i solved it.
Your aggregation query would look like this :

```
"aggs": {
"2": {
  "date_histogram": {
    "field": "startDate",
    "interval": "month",
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "sum": {
        "script": "((condition) ? 1 : 0)",
        "lang": "expression"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Note that you can also try it with defining your script as a .groovy file in the scripts folder of ElasticSearch installation.

Hope that it'll help.

Regards.